# What are the steps to opening a .dat file in java?

Tags: file

I have another assignment which is obviously giving me trouble.
I need to write code that will open a .dat file from my hard drive in Netbeans IDE.
The file doesn't contain binary data just simple text characters.
When I run the code I've written it gives an error...because it cannot locate the file. Any Suggestions

```
package countedcones;

import java.io.*;

public class CountedCones {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

        FileReader in = new FileReader("icecream.dat");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        in.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just put right path to file!

Comment: Can you be more specific...have i left something out...!

Comment: How do I put the file in the right PATH? Thanks!

Comment: File is probably not in working directory of your java process, so try to supply full path to file.